# Python 'test' module produces "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python

I have tried to use `test` module a lot of times and in a lot of different ways. I always get "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable". Here is an example that I have copy-pasted from http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/list_algorithms.html:

```
import test

def search_linear(xs, target):
  """ Find and return the index of target in sequence xs """
  for (i, v) in enumerate(xs):
    if v == target: return i
  return -1

friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
test(search_linear(friends, "Zoe") == 1)
```

The error is produced on the last line.

I run Python 2.7.13.

Comment: You should be using python 3 by now. Python 2 reaches the end of its life in just over 2 months

Comment: Please include the whole error message in the question.

Comment: If read the instructions and [follow the exercises](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/fruitful_functions.html#unit-testing), you'll see that `test` is a function you should have defined earlier on, not a module you need to import.

Comment: `test` is a module, not a function or any other callable type. Is there a function *in* the module (perhaps *also* named `test`) that you want to use? `test.test(...)` or `from test import test`.

Comment: @dangee1705. Thanks, but this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ruzihm. I think I wrote the whole error message in the title.

Comment: @Apostolos it is very relavent, as you should have definitely moved over to python 3 by this point

Comment: I was hoping for a stack trace but now I agree with b_c. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/405359). I advise ceasing attempts to "use" the `test` module, and instead defining a `test` function as the tutorial instructs.

Answer (score 0):

On the last line it should be `test.test(search_linear(friends, "Zoe") == 1)` or `test(test.search_linear(friends, "Zoe") == 1)` because you have just imported test